# MSProject: How to set up different resource availability for different workdays?

Tags: ms-project, resources

I need to set up a resource with the following availability in MS Project:

Mon 50%
Tue 50%
Wed 100%
Thu 50%
Fri 0%

Is this possible?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Laszlo

Comment: I need to do something similar and need this level of granularity because the resources are only part-time or can only dedicate certain hours to the project. If I keep it at 8 hour days when the resource can only work 4, then I can't schedule their work across the week and the task is finished mid-Wednesday instead of the actual time of Friday.
This also links back into the cost management side. Leaving it as 8hour days doubles the cost result because of the doubled number of hours.
How is it possible to set the resources in this manner? Regards,
Matthew

Answer (score 2):

You could model this in the Resource Calendar by having the Resource "work" only between certain times of the day on certain days of the week. Henceforth that resource can be applied 100% to a task but will nonetheless only perform work on the days/times on which you have declared it is available.

A downside of this will be that you will need to set it up manually in each sub-project if it is time-shared amongst projects.

Answer (score 0):

That's a tremendously low level of granularity.  Tracking that would offer very little value over taking it up a notch and tracking at that level.  For example, instead of changing the unit value per day, take an average or something close based on that variability per week.  Even better, per month...depending on the scope of your project.

Our work performance is probabilistic.  Not deterministic.  Getting that precise only means you are banking on something that has an extremely low likelihood of coming true.  You will end up chasing this degree of exactness and you WILL lose sight of the bigger picture.

Comment: I know what you mean. Usually I don't do this with work resources, but I have good reasons to need it now. I may not use the proper tool in MSProject. Imagine many subprojects, and each of these subprojects need a server computer for half day during their lifetime. Timing is unimportant. Server availability varies by workdays.

Comment: In that case, the only other "easy" solution I can think of is name the resource differently, e.g., Tom Smith who has 100% units and Tom Smith1 who has 50% units.  Will this work?

Comment: Not really, but you gave me an idea. Both will have 50% units, one works only on wed, the other works mon-thu. And I put them in a resource pool. Edited - to think about it, your solution would work, too, with the addition of the resource pool. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure, good luck.